# What Difference between sensors and intelligent sensors

Tags: sensor, sensing

I was studying about sensors. I'm confused about the diffence between Sensors and Intelligent Sensors. Both seem same to me !!

Comment: It would help if you provide a link to examples of such products. There are thousands of different types of sensors. Maybe "intelligent" is just a marketing term. It could be that there is a micro controller build into the sensor, some companies then call it "intelligent".

Comment: Thank You. Actually I didnot look for products. I'm studying a paper named "Intelligent Sensors and Actuators" , so I got this confusion.

Comment: @MathuMathi  In that case, please post a link to this paper which you are studying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of electrical engineering a sensor is just something that interprets some type of data, (like light, or sound) into a useable format for engineers. For example, a [photodiode](https://www.thorlabs.de/images/xlarge/12174-xl.jpg) will convert light to a proportional amount of current. This is a dumb sensor. An engineer will need additional circuitry to read and understand the data depending on design, such as op-amps, D2As, etc etc. **A sensor is a stand-alone device.**

A smart sensor is a broad term but generally means it has the built in additional circuitry for a designer. For example, this [motion sensor](https://content.solarbotics.com/products/photos/acb31483454e0b54b8c27b7a1c450ffd/lrg/50827-09587-01-working.jpg) has an op-amp and digital circuitry built into the sensor module so you can plug it in and start using it right away. With digital or analog signals you can adjust its sensitivity and output range rather than adding amplifiers, A2Ds, and D2As to do it yourself. **A smart sensor has additional circuitry to aid the designer's job of using and understanding the data.** In the picture of the motion sensor, the white thing is just a "dumb" sensor, but the ICs, resistors, caps, and header make the module "smart".